# AWS Amplify Auth - 'Remember me' functionality for 'withAuthenticator'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

By default Amplify Auth stores session information and tokens in `localStorage` and it is possible to configure it to use `sessionStorage` to achieve not remembering user's sign in.

```
Amplify.configure({
 Auth: {
  storage: window.sessionStorage
 }
})
```

It also would be necessary to use custom authenticator UI as hosted one does not provide such functionality

```
withAuthenticator(App, true, [
 <SignIn/>  //with 'RememberMe' option
])
```

My question is it okay to reconfigure Amplify Auth right from `<SignIn/>` component to use another storage type?
And if I do so, how to tell Amplify which storage to check for saved session in case of page reload?
Or is there a better way to achieve such functionality?

Comment: is this functionality (remeber me) not build in amplify by default already ?